# Loop for loading and saving .mat files

Tags: matlab, file-io, mat-file

I have a folder with .mat files, and I want to write a loop for loading these files and doing some actions with data:

1) Choose my folder of data files

2) Perform the following set of operations (pseudocode):

```
for i = 1:99
    load 'Data0i.mat' ('Datai.mat', if i > 9);
    data = data * 10;
    save data as 'Data0i.mat' to another folder;
end;
```

What's the MATLAB implementation?

Comment: Well, it is not matlab implementation, it's just an algorithm. I have problems with strings. How should I change data folders and how to provide numbers in names of files?

Comment: there is `sprintf()` in matlab. you might also need `dir()` for getting the file list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matlab file name with zero-padded numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213442/matlab-file-name-with-zero-padded-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
inputFolder = 'infolder';
outputFolder = 'outfolder';

for i = 1:99
    %# Load data
    inputFilename = sprintf('%s/%02d.mat', inputFolder, i);
    load(inputFilename)

    %# Process data
    data = data * 10;

    %# Savedata
    outputFilename = sprintf('%s/%02d.mat', outputFolder, i);
    save(outputFilename, 'data')
end
```