# Loop through a series of .mat files in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, file-io, mat-file

I have 12 mat files (one for each month) that need to be used individually for a calculation. They are too big to load all twelve at one time. There fore I would like to call month #1, do the calculation, call month #2, ...#12.

I have done this with .asc files in the past, but am having trouble with. mat files.

I am trying the following:

```
matObj = matfile('tempOR_norm.mat')

matObj = 

  matlab.io.MatFile

  Properties:
      Properties.Source: 'C:\GIS_DATA\SNOW\Programs\SNOW\tempOR_norm.mat'
    Properties.Writable: false                                           
         tempOR_01_norm: [1424x1817 double]                              
         tempOR_02_norm: [1424x1817 double]                              
         tempOR_03_norm: [1424x1817 double]                              
         tempOR_04_norm: [1424x1817 double]                              
         tempOR_05_norm: [1424x1817 double]                              
         tempOR_06_norm: [1424x1817 double]                              
         tempOR_07_norm: [1424x1817 double]                              
         tempOR_08_norm: [1424x1817 double]                              
         tempOR_09_norm: [1424x1817 double]                              
         tempOR_10_norm: [1424x1817 double]                              
         tempOR_11_norm: [1424x1817 double]                              
         tempOR_12_norm: [1424x1817 double]
```

But how do I loop through this list?

I need something along the lines of

```
input = load(matObj(i))
```

but this give me:

> MatFile objects are scalar. Access variables using the syntax
>   objName.varName(indices).

Any insight would be appreciated!

-Thanks-

Answer (score 1):

Got it (with help from [Loop for loading and saving .mat files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600519/loop-for-loading-and-saving-mat-files)):

it goes like this...

```
 for i = 1:12;
        if (i <= 9)
            filename = ['tempOR_0', int2str(i), '_norm.mat'];
        else    filename = ['tempOR_', int2str(i), '_norm.mat'];
        end
 end

load(filename);
```

Comment: you could replace the if/else statement with: `filename = sprintf('tempOR_%02d_norm.mat',i);`

Answer (score 0):

if you dont even know the file names try `dir()` command, if I'm recalling correctly you can specify what file extensions to return with `dir(./*.mat)`. You can find more stuff from http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/techdoc/ref/dir.html