# Matlab file name with zero-padded numbers

Tags: matlab, string-formatting

I have 11x11 matrices and I saved them as `.mat` files from `F01_01` to `F11_11`. 
I have to run a function `Func` on each file. Since it takes a long time, I want to write a script to run the function automatically:

```
for i=01:11  
    for j=01:11  
        filename=['F',num2str(i), '_', num2str(j),'.mat'];  
        load(filename);  
        Func(Fi_j);   % run the function for each file  Fi_j  
    end  
end
```

But it doesn't work, Matlab cannot find the mat-files.
Could somebody please help ?

Comment: No problem in the code you posted? what error you are facing?

Comment: For future troubleshooting: use `dbstop if error` to figure out where the problem occurs, and inspect all variables on that line very carefully.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### The problem

```
i=01; 
j=01; 
['F',num2str(i), '_', num2str(j),'.mat']
```

evaluates to

> F1_1.mat

and not to

> F01_01.mat

as expected.

The reason for this is that `i=01` is a double type assignment and `i` equals to `1` - there are no leading zeros for these types of variables.

### A solution

a possible solution for the problem would be

```
for ii = 1:11
    for jj= 1:11
        filename = sprintf('F_%02d_%02d.mat', ii, jj );
        load(filename);  
        Func(Fi_j);   % run the function for each file  Fi_j  
     end  
end
```

#### Several comments:

1. Note the use of `sprintf` to format the double `ii` and `jj` with leading zero using `%02d`.
2. You can use the second argument of [`num2str`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html) to format its output, e.g.: `num2str(ii,'%02d')`.
3. It is a good practice to use [string formatting](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html) tools when dealing with strings.
4. It is a better practice in matlab [**not** to use `i` and `j` as loop counters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab), since their default value in matlab is `sqrt(-1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate solution, note that the solution by @[Shai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14214042/1714410) is more easily expanded to multiple digits but this one requires less understanding of string formatting.

```
for i=1:11  
        for j=1:11  
            filename=['F',num2str(floor(i/10)),num2str(mod(i,10)) '_', num2str(floor(j/10)),num2str(mod(j,10)),'.mat'];  
            load(filename);  
            Func(Fi_j);   % run the function for each file  Fi_j  
       end  
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The `num2str` can do zeropadding to fill the field. In the example below 4 is the desired field width+1.

```
num2str(1,'% 04.f')
```

Ans = `001`