# How can I load 100 files with similar names and/or string in just one step in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, ascii, filenames, string-formatting, matlab-load

I have 100 ASCII files in my directory all named as follows:

> int_001.ASC
>   int_002.ASC
>   int_003.ASC
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   int_099.ASC
>   int_100.ASC

I have to import them in MATLAB all with importdata, which should work as follows:

```
A = importdata('int_001.ASC', ' ', 9)
x = A.data(:,1)
y = A.data(:,2)
```

My question is: how can I avoid writing 100 times `importdata`? Is there a way to write the first string only and then have all data uploaded?

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

```
fls = dir( 'int_*.ASC' );
for fi=1:numel(fls)
    A{fi} = importdata( fls(fi).name, ' ', 9 );
    % ...
end
```

**UPDATE:**
You may use [string formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213442/matlab-file-name-with-zero-padded-numbers?lq=1) to read the files according to their numbers:

```
for fi=1:100
    A{fi} = importdata( sprintf('int_%03d.ASC', fi ), ' ', 9 );
    % ...
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `strcat` function in a for loop :

```
for k=1:n
    fileName = strcat('int_',num2str(k, '%03d'),'.ASC');
    A(k) = importdata(fileName, ' ', 9);
    x(k) = A(k).data(:,1);
    y(k) = A(k).data(:,2);
end
```

Comment: Maybe I've come to the point. By using fls = dir('int_*.ASC') now we have fls(1) = int_091.ASC. I typed fls(1) and what appears is: name = 'int_091.ASC', date = ... and so on. The problem is that if I do importdata('int_091.ASC', ' ', 9) everything is all right; instead, if I do importdata(fls(1), ' ', 9), MATLAB cannot work it out. Should I use a different command?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to take this a little overboard:

```
alldata = arrayfun(...
    @(dirEntry)importdata(dirEntry.name, ' ', 9), ...
    dir('int_*.ASC'),...
    'uniformoutput',false);
```

This line does the following

1. Gets a listing of all files matching the partial filename, as an array of structures (h/t Shai)
2. For each element in that array, performs the `importdata` call from your original post.
3. Compiles all the outputs into a cell array.