# Opening multiple files with similar names in MATLAB: importdata cannot open the files given the name by strcat or dir

Tags: matlab, file-io, filenames

As [Shai and CTZStef suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15366374/how-can-i-load-100-files-with-similar-names-and-or-string-in-just-one-step-in-ma/15366423#15366423), when I have to open multiple files with similar names in MATLAB, I have to do

```
for k=1:size(fls)
    fileName = strcat('int_',num2str(k),'.ASC');
    A(k) = importdata(fileName, ' ', 9);
    x(k) = A(k).data(:,1);
    y(k) = A(k).data(:,2);
end
```

or also

```
fls = dir('int_00_*.ASC');
for fi=1:numel(fls)
    A(fi) = importdata(fls(fi).name, ' ',9);
end
```

Well, the problem is that none of them works.
What should I do? Is it a problem with my MATLAB version?

Comment: Please state what the "none of them works". Looking at your other questions, I would say you have problems constructing filenames.

Comment: @Dedek Mraz if I declare the filename with fls or strcat, ie I do fls = dir(...) and then I write fls(2) or fls(56), that's all right: it's the right filename. The problem is that importdata doesn't "like" opening the files in this way

Comment: Again, I don't know what you are trying to load, but putting it into a field in an array looks wrong. Maybe this is the problem? Did you try assigning it to `A{fi}`?

Comment: @Dedek Mraz Usually when you open a file with importdata you do: importdata(filename, ' ', #lines). This works as long as you have one file only. What I am wondering is: how can you do when you have many files to open and they all have similar names? People suggested putting the files in a loop, but it doesn't work

Comment: @Shai yes, as I am new to this forum I don't know how it works... should I rather have kept the previous question open?

Comment: @ragnar: what I'm saying is that you assign an array from the file to a single field in array `A`. I'm assuming you have multiple values in one file. This will not work. Again: have you tried with `A{fi}`?

Comment: @Shai OK, I'll bear it in mind for the future

Comment: @DedekMraz yes, and it doesn't work. But maybe Shai has suggested the solution I should have followed and I didn't because I didn't read it properly

Answer (score 2):

You need to follow the answers you got more closely:

1. The `strcat` solution CANNOT handle the zero padding of the file names. You'll ahve to **manually** rename all files from `'int_001.ASC'` to  `'int_1.ASC'`.
   **UPDATE** (due to @DedekMraz's comment): you'll need to modify the `strcat` input string to `strcat('int_', num2str( k, '%03d' ), '.ASC');`
2. You can use a strategy similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213442/matlab-file-name-with-zero-padded-numbers?lq=1). See the update to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15366423/1714410) you already got.
3. The input you gave your `dir` function is **wrong** it has to be `dir('int_*.ASC')` and not `dir('int_00_*.ASC')`.

Comment: For padding you can just use `num2str(k,'%03d')`. I think this should pad the integer with leading zeros

Comment: @Shai OK, I'll try to be more specific. The biggest problem is that I'd have to manually change the names of 256 files that are something like int_00_091_000.ASC, with only 000 being fixed. The other two digit series vary in different ways and I must keep them just as they are because they are important to know what's inside the files. Having said that I have noticed the error message is always "error using importdata: unable to open file". Therefore the files are properly "marked" (if I type fls(34) I got int_01_092_000.ASC: all right). The problem is with importdata. I'll try with sprintf

Comment: @ragnar - please see the update regarding zero padding in `str2num` (READ UPDATES TO ANSWERS). try using `importdata` with full file name (including full path). You might want to look at `fullfile` command for that.